# Correct way to write mantainable tests for React pure components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Im entering the world of test for React pure components written for JestJS.
In a guide I read that its simpler to write tests for pure components, that will generate less problems once wrapped in complex uis.

So let's suppose I have this component:

```js
    const Icon = ({
      name,
      size,
      rotate,
      flip,
      spin,
      color,
      className,
      onClick
    }) => (
      <i
        className={[
          "icon",
          color,
          className,
          "font",
          "font-" + name,
          size ? "font-" + size + "px" : null,
          rotate ? "font-rotate-" + rotate : null,
          flip ? "font-flip-" + flip : null,
          spin ? "font-spin" : null
        ].join(" ")}
        onClick={onClick}
      />
    );

    Icon.propTypes = {
      name: PropTypes.oneOf(names).isRequired,
      size: PropTypes.oneOf(sizes),
      rotate: PropTypes.oneOf(rotates),
      flip: PropTypes.oneOf(flips),
      spin: PropTypes.bool,
      className: PropTypes.string,
      color: PropTypes.oneOf(colors),
      onClick: PropTypes.func
    };

    Icon.defaultProps = {
      size: null,
      rotate: null,
      flip: null,
      spin: false,
      className: "",
      color: null,
      onClick: () => {}
    };
```

`names`, `sizes`, `rotates`, `flips` and `colors` are constants inside the component class.

Now, let's say I want to write a test (I'm using Enzyme for mounting) in order to check that my component will render correctly.

I wrote a code similar to this:

```js
    import React from "react";
    import { mount } from "enzyme";
    import Icon from "../../components/icon";
    describe("Icon component", () => {
        it("should render an icon", () => {
            const wrap = mount(<Icon name={props.name} />);
            expect(wrap.find(`i.icon.font.font-${props.name}`).exists()).toBe(true);
        });
    });
```

But here are my doubts:

1. Is it worth to create tests for each prop that could be passed to my component?
2. If yes, should I write a test for each possibile combination of the accepted props?
3. If yes, when I will add/remove/change a prop in future, should that change be reflected on adding/removing/changing an exponential amount of tests?

Answer (score 0):

you may use [snapshot testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing) and provide just few test cases with different combinations of props. Something like making photo to later compare with.

To me covering each prop in isolation or props combination is neither ensure you it's 100% fine(what if css class is just missing in styles?) nor runs quick. Unit tests should be easy to support and understand, and they should not make build process struggle. Fast smoke tests that run on each repository push is better than exhausting tests with 100% coverage that are never triggered because it takes 1 hour to pass.